# How to write a bat file to rename files in file hierarchy

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I'm have a lot of pictures in a file system. I'm trying to figure out a way to rename all of the files, and if possible put them in one folder. At the very least rename them where they are.

They are currently in a hierarchy like this:

```
folder1\folder2\filename.jpg
```

Is there any way I can write a script to rename the files so the name of the actual file would be:

```
folder1-folder2-filename.jpg
```

I'm not sure how to go about this. Any suggestions or a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
for %%* in (.) do set name=%%~pn*
set name=%name:\=-%
set name=%name:~1%
```

%name% now has the folder name. add this to your file name.